# Entering and Returning multiple values with (...) in a function without using tables?

Tags: lua

Here is what I want to do:

```
-- I want to do something like this
local a = entity:getMultiple(aType)
local a, b = entity:getMultiple(aType, bType)
```

I want to enter multiple values into the function and get the values back, changed, based on what I have given. Without the use of tables.

With tables this is a simple task, but it has the downsides of allocating memory every time this function is ran. This function may be run up to several thousands of times per second so I want to avoid that if possible.

I ended up with something like this:

```
function Entity:getMultiple(a, b, c, d, e)
  if b == nil then
    return self[a]
  end
  if c == nil then
    return self[a], self[b]
  end
  if d == nil then
    return self[a], self[b], self[c]
  end
  if e == nil then
    return self[a], self[b], self[c], self[d]
  end
  return self[a], self[b], self[c], self[d], self[e]
end
```

But I feel like there might be a better a way to do this. Maybe with the Lua's `select()` function or something else. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Remove the ifs and just return all 5, indexing by nil is fine. Despite returning a bunch of nils (which has no effect programming wise) its even a bit faster for me.

Comment: @Luke100000 Ah cool, for some reason I thought it would complain if I try and ask for nil in a table! Great that lua does that. However for one reason or another the if's was faster for me when all 5 values were filled out. The speed difference was negligible when there were only one or two. I'm using LuaJIT in love2d so maybe its because of that.

Comment: Hmm, then I think you are already close to whats possible. Another approach would be a lookup map of functions, and you use `#arg` as index. It's the same speed for me, but may scale better with more arguments. Tho it feels quite hacky.

Comment: Just tested again with the if statements removed and looks the the speed difference was pretty much the same. Probably just os process randomness. Also tested the function lookup map, the speed was pretty much the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Using Select

I did find a solution somewhat:

```
local gm = {}
function Entity:getMultiple(...)
  local len = select("#", ...)

  for i = 1, len do
    local arg = select(i, ...)
    gm[i] = self[arg] -- Modify the value based on arg here
  end

  return unpack(gm, 1, len) -- or table.unpack()
end
```

The reasoning was that even even though I'm using a table here, I was thinking that it may only be allocated a few times since I'm reusing the same table.

**Massive caveat though**, this solution ran significantly slower for me (from 0.0003 seconds to 0.16 seconds, a 500x speed difference) compared to the if statement solution I had above in my version of LuaJit and Love2D. If you're using other versions of Lua though the result might be different.

---

### 2. Return Directly

For now I'll be sticking to a modified version I originally had:

```lua
function Entity:get(a) 
  if a == nil then return nil end -- Must do a nil check
  return self[a] -- Return the modified value
end

function Entity:getMultiple(a, b, c, d, e)
  return self:get(a), self:get(b), self:get(c), self:get(d), self:get(e)
end

-- Then you can use it in this way
local a = en:getMultiple(aType)
local a, b = en:getMultiple(aType, bType)
```

### 3. Function lookup table

EDIT: If you're a stickler for performance like me this part might be of interest.
Luke100000 mentioned instead of using multitudes of If-statements, you could use a lookup table of functions, and use the length of (...) as the index.

I needed to have up to 20 inputs, and having 20 if-statements hurt performance, that being said it was not as much as I thought. (100000 iterations in 0.001 seconds). Even then though I wanted to see if the lookup tables were faster.

The performance of lookup using the index was as speedy as the original (ran 100000 times at 0.0003 seconds), but without the downsides of slowing down even with a high amount of arguments.

Here is what the general code looks like:

```
-- Creates a look up table that looks a bit like this:
local unfurlLookup = {
   [1] = function(fn, self, a1)
      return
          fn(self, a1)
   end,
   [2] = function(fn, self, a1, a2)
      return
          fn(self, a1),
          fn(self, a2)
   end,
   [3] = function(fn, self, a1, a2, a3)
      return
          fn(self, a1),
          fn(self, a2),
          fn(self, a3)
   end
   ...
}

-- Run `fn` on each element and return the result
function unfurl(fn, self, ...)
   local len = select("#", ...)
   return unfurlLookup[len](fn, self, ...)
end
```

So I've created an "unfurl" function so it can be used generally. That way I wont need to create lookup map more than once.

However it's a pain to write 30 functions and put it into a table, so I utilized `loadstring` to generate the functions for me:

```lua
-- Generate the lookup table with `loadstring`
local ufl = "return { \n"
for i = 1, 30 do
   ufl = ufl .. "[" .. i .. "] = function(fn, self, "
   for j = 1, i - 1 do
      ufl = ufl .. " a" .. j .. ", "
   end
   ufl = ufl .. " a" .. i
   ufl = ufl .. ")\n"
   ufl = ufl .. "return\n"
   for j = 1, i - 1 do
      ufl = ufl .. "  fn(self, a" .. j .. "), \n"
   end

   ufl = ufl .. " fn(self, a" .. i .. ") \nend, "
end
ufl = ufl .. " \n}"

local unfurlLookup = loadstring(ufl)()

-- We create a general "unfurl" function. We only need to do this once so save it for later use
function unfurl(fn, self, ...)
   local len = select("#", ...)
   return unfurlLookup[len](fn, self, ...)
end

-- "Unfurl" Usage:
local getter = function(self, p)
   return self[p]
end

function getMultiple(self, ...)
   return unfurl(getter, self, ...)
end
```

Then use it normally

```
local tbl = {}
local a = getMultiple(tbl, aType)
local a, b = getMultiple(tbl, aType, bType)
```

### Conclusion

Here are the speed results of the various solutions:

```
Ran 100,000 times for each. 20 Inputs/ arguments for each
With Tables:   0.3000 seconds
Recursion:     0.2800 seconds 
Select:        0.1700 seconds
If statements: 0.0010 seconds
Lookup table:  0.0003 seconds
```

As you can see the lookup table performed the fastest, even if it's not the nicest to look at. Good thing though, you can just create the lookup table once and use the unfurl function as many times you want.

With using fresh tables each iteration it was the slowest. Probably  unsurprising since you have to allocate for the table each time. This also adds the future overhead of the garbage collector needing to clean it up as well, so this actually might be slower

The result with recursion (from Luatics post) was surprising to me. To me it looks like a great solution, but unfortunately on my end it was almost as slow as the tables.

Perhaps unsurprisingly the lookup tables performed the best. That being said, take these results with a grain of salt, since I'm using LuaJit and I had 20 inputs for the (...). At one or two inputs, the results weren't as pronounced as I have here.

I probably don't need that much performance anyway, but I've put the results of my finding here anyway for anyone if they want to use it.

Comment: Note also that you can arrange your `if`-statements in a tree to speed finding the code to use up (rather than having them laid out linearly).

Comment: Could you provide your benchmarking code? The results seem very surprising to me. Differences of ~1000x are very unexpected. I'd expect something between 10x-100x, but this looks like LuaJIT is completely optimizing some things out.

Answer (score 0):

Your first proposed solution has a memory leak: `gm` holds references to values even after you are done with them. To fix it, either create fresh tables (are you sure that this is such a massive issue? several thousand objects per second isn't a lot), or set the values of `gm` to `nil` after you're done with it. This will make the solution even slower (though it definitely shouldn't be "500x" slower).

Note also that Lua never shrinks tables: If you call `getMultiple` with a thousand arguments, `gm` will always have at least a thousand slots. This may also be considered a memleak, though usually not as severe. The only way to reclaim the memory is to use a fresh table.

An alternative way to process varargs that doesn't involve a temporary table is to simply use a recursive function. If we can assume that your vararg ends with a `nil` (that is, there will never be a "hole" in your argument list), this can be written as follows:

```lua
local function getMultiple(self, key, ...)
    if key == nil then return end
    return self[key], getMultiple(self, ...)
end
Entity.getMultiple = getMultiple
```

I've used a local function and avoided a closure here in the hopes that it helps performance. If you do want to deal with `nil`s properly (returning a `nil` for every `nil` and not stopping at the first `nil`), you'll have to use `select` and keep a counter, which may hurt performance:

```lua
local function getMultiple(self, n, key, ...)
    if n == 0 then return end
    return self[key], getMultiple(self, n-1, ...)
end
function Entity:getMultiple(...)
    return getMultiple(self, select("#", ...), ...)
end
```

You could consider using a closure, but this would come with a heap allocation, and upvalue access is typically slower than parameter access (however you save having to pass the `self` and `n` parameters, which also saves stack space).

Comment: Setting it to nil is a possibility, though I think 20 references in a table wouldn't be too memory heavy so I wouldn't mind having it there just so Lua doesn't shrink the table after a while. Using recursion though is actually interesting idea. Unfortunately I tested it and for some reason it performed even slower than the select method (about ~800x to 1000x compared to the original if statement one). Not sure why it would do that though, the recursive function looks fine to me. Maybe recursion doesn't play too well with LuaJit, the constant passing of ellipsis, or self variable I'm not sure.

Comment: @Flare the problem isn't about the references (the 20 pointers), it's about what lives behind them. That should be collected eventually, but if your `gm` table holds a reference to it, it won't be. There could be a table with a billion elements kept alive via a reference in the `gm` table.